# Time Subtract in PHP

Tags: php, time, subtraction

I need help to subtract 2 times in PHP.

Example:

```
$date1 = 02:40;
$date2 = 00:00;

$finaldate = $date1 - $date2;
```

the correct answer will be 21:20.

Comment: How is this possible: `02:40 - 00:00 = 21:20`?

Comment: Are you trying to find the difference between 2.40 pm and 12 midnight?

Comment: that is not going to work....

Comment: not finding the diference... taking 2 hour and 40 min from time

Comment: same if you do 100 - 20 = 80, but i want with time

Comment: i look everywhere and i find just to get the difference in hours.

Comment: looked every where? there is a link to the right with the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check it out:

if use `$date2` as `24:00`

```
$date1 = new DateTime('02:40');
$date2 = new DateTime('24:00');
$finaldate = $date2->diff($date1);
echo $finaldate->format('%h:%i'); // 21:20
```

But if use `$date2` as `00:00`

```
$date1 = new DateTime('02:40');
$date2 = new DateTime('00:00');
$finaldate = $date2->diff($date1);
echo $finaldate->format('%h:%i'); //02:40
```

Comment: Never compare with God!. Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

use `strtotime()` and subtract both the times ...

```
<?php 

$date1=strtotime("02:40");
$date2=strtotime("00:00");
$diff= date('H:i', $date2-$date1);
echo "Time Difference : ".$diff;

?>
```

This will output:

```
Time Difference : 21:20
```